# Sorting an array of objects based on string property in Typescript

Tags: typescript, sorting, angular7

I have an array of objects like so:

```
0: {id: "743", name: "F"}
1: {id: "786", name: "S"}
2: {id: "903", name: "B"}
3: {id: "988", name: "L"}
4: {id: "1202", name: "S"}
5: {id: "1355", name: "H"}
6: {id: "1374", name: "R"}
```

And I need to sort the array of objects based on the 'name' property.

I have searched around for the answer and have tried each of them out but with no joy.
The two main answers I came across were:

```
Array.sort((leftSide, rightSide): number => {
            if (leftSide.name.toLowerCase() < rightSide.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
            if (leftSide.name.toLowerCase() > rightSide.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
```

and

```
Array.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

both of these just give me the same unsorted array output. Is there any other way to do this? I am using Angular 7.

Full code:

```
getDeviceBrands(): void {
        this.deviceBrands = new Array<DeviceBrand>();
        const parentNodeId = 0;

        this.chartsService.getCatalogNodes(parentNodeId, this.catalogName).subscribe(catalogNodes => {
            catalogNodes.forEach(n => {
                this.deviceBrands.push({
                    id: n.CatalogNodeId.toString(),
                    name: n.Name
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(this.deviceBrands);

        const sorted = this.deviceBrands.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);

        console.log(sorted);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you're not showing us the actual shape of the array you're trying to sort.  is it like `let arr = [{id: "...", name: "...", ...]` or `let arr = [{0: {id: "...", name: "...",},},]` 'cause that matters.

Comment: `Array` is a built-in type, `Array.sort()` doesn't exist. What is the actual code/example?

Comment: @Andreas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

how do you format code in comments?

Comment: @MattMorgan What I have posted is the shape of the array. Its an array of an object called 'DeviceBrand' and there is 2 properties ID and Name

Comment: `Array.sort() !== Array.prototype.sort()`

Comment: @Andreas ah okay. If I go to definition I get this:
 sort(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): this;

Comment: it looks like the casing on `name`/`Name` is mixed up

Comment: The collection I am retrieving the name from has the property 'Name' but the array I am pushing it to has a property 'name'

Comment: @OliverRadini your comment gave me the idea to do the sort within my subscribe and that has worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was doing the sort too late! If you need to edit a collection in anyway and you are using a subscribe to fill your collection then add the code within the subscribe!

I did not include my full code at first which is what caused confusion as the answers supplied all worked. This is a good example of why you should include full code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the above doesn't work for you; but the following works for me:

```js
const x = [
  { id: "743", name: "F" },
  { id: "786", name: "S" },
  { id: "903", name: "B" },
  { id: "988", name: "L" },
  { id: "1202", name: "S" },
  { id: "1355", name: "H" },
  { id: "1374", name: "R" },
];

const sorted = x.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);

console.log(sorted);
```

From running your code, it seems like it ought to work as well. I'm guessing from the example you've shown that you're using the array in a variable named `Array`, which is not a good idea, as `Array` is already used in javascript.

```js
const Array = [
  { id: "743", name: "F" },
  { id: "786", name: "S" },
  { id: "903", name: "B" },
  { id: "988", name: "L" },
  { id: "1202", name: "S" },
  { id: "1355", name: "H" },
  { id: "1374", name: "R" },
];

const sorted = Array.sort((leftSide, rightSide) => {
    if (leftSide.name.toLowerCase() < rightSide.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (leftSide.name.toLowerCase() > rightSide.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure why the above doesn't work..."_ - Then the question is not a [mcve] and you shouldn't add a _"it works"_ answer but instead ask for an actual [mcve] or just vote to close.

Comment: @Andreas you may be correct, if I don't hear back from the original poster then I'll delete this answer

Comment: I just replaced the name I was using with the word Array not actually naming my array that in my code.

Comment: @JamesBlackburn Then can you provide some further info, because what you have should work

Comment: `getDeviceBrands(): void {
      this.deviceBrands = new Array<DeviceBrand>();
        const parentNodeId = 0;
        this.chartsService.getCatalogNodes(parentNodeId, this.catalogName).subscribe(catalogNodes => {
            catalogNodes.forEach(n => {
                this.deviceBrands.push({
                    id: n.CatalogNodeId.toString(),
                    name: n.Name
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(this.deviceBrands);
        const sorted = this.deviceBrands.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);
        console.log(sorted);
    }`

Comment: Theres the complete code but not sure how to format it properly within comments

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: Updated in question